# How can I hide the //tsclient/<drive> connection in Windows XP Mode

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-xp

When XP Mode is started, it automatically creates \tsclient connections to the drives on the Windows 7 computer that is starting it.  So for example c: becomes \tsclient\c etc etc.

Although I want these to be accessible, I want to hide them from the user that logs on, much like it is possible under to hide drive letters from users under XP/7.  Is it possible to do this?